# define layout in Yii WebModules

Tags: php, module, yii

I'm going to use a web module in my web project.what I want to do is to use my original theme of the project for it's layout.but when I write this code on my module class in the file DefaultController (my modul name is cpanel) nothing happens and the module can't load the layout from theme.here is my code :

```
class DefaultController extends Controller {

    public function actionIndex() {
        $this->layout = "column2";
        $this->render('index');
    }

}
```

Is there anything wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

```
$this->layout = '//layouts/column2';
$this->render('index');
```

Make sure you have the 'column2.php' layout file in your 'layouts' folder: `\protected\views\layouts\`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem.there was a line in my layout view page (column2.php) which get the main view content.

```
$this->beginContent('//layouts/main');
```

I removed the first slash and it did work for me.just changed it to this :

```
$this->beginContent('/layouts/main');
```